# Find value in other file if it match print

Tags: awk

In the following case. I will like to find values which match in: file1: columns 5 & 6 with file2: columns 1

If the values are exactly the same in both files, then print like the desired output file

**file1**

```
31429,36689,313212.5,2334362.5,30001,35825,31308,302412.50 2316512.50
31429,36701,313362.5,2334362.5,31429,36681,31311,2334363,31429
31429,36713,313512.5,2334362.5,31429,36719,31358,303312.50 2316512.50
31429,36749,313962.5,2334362.5,31429,36751,31398,2334362,31429
31429,36809,314712.5,2334362.5,31429,36803,31463,2334361,31429
31429,36821,314862.5,2334362.5,30001,35945,31481,2334363,31429
```

**file2**

```
3000135825 302412.50 2316512.50
3000135837 302562.50 2316512.50
3000135849 302712.50 2316512.50
3000135861 302862.50 2316512.50
3000135873 303012.50 2316512.50
3000135885 303162.50 2316512.50
3000135897 303312.50 2316512.50
3000135909 303462.50 2316512.50
3000135921 303612.50 2316512.50
3000135933 303762.50 2316512.50
3000135945 303912.50 2316512.50
```

**output desired**

```
3000135825 302412.50 2316512.50 30001 35825
3000135945 303912.50 2316512.50 30001 35945
```

**I tried**

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$5 OFS $6]=$5 $6
  next
}
(($1) in a){
  print $0,a[$1]
}
' FS="[, ]"  file1 FS=" "  file2
```

Comment: The question here is, do fields 5 and 6 of file1 always have 5 characters, no exceptions? And does field 1 in file2 always have 10 characters? What if some characters are missing, how is this handled.

Comment: revert the content of `a` (`a[$5 $6] = $5 OFS $6`). The `in` statement checks if a key is part of the array, not if the value is part of the array (`a[key] = value`)

Comment: I hope `12345` -> `123` and`45` or `12` and `345` not an issue for your problem

Comment: kvantour , do fields 5 and 6 of file1 always have 5 characters, no exceptions? And does field 1 in file2 always have 10 characters?  \yes it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner may help:

```
awk -F'[, ]' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$5$6 in a{print a[$5$6],$5,$6}' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this would be:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$5 $6]=$5;b[$5 $6]=$6;next;} $1 in a{print $0,a[$1],b[$1]}' file1 FS=' ' file2
3000135825 302412.50 2316512.50 30001 35825
3000135945 303912.50 2316512.50 30001 35945
```

Or avoid setting `FS` the second time:

```
awk -F'[, ]' 'NR==FNR{a[$5 $6]=$5;b[$5 $6]=$6;next;} $1 in a{print $0,a[$1],b[$1]}' file1 file2
```